# Have UITextView make first line current cursor position?

Tags: iphone, cursor, scroll, uitextview

Long story short I need to get a UITextView to automatically scroll to the current cursor line, however I need one additional thing. Instead of just having the TextView be scrolled "in view", I need the cursor line to be in view specifically as the first line of the textView.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: Need some clarification on the last point about the first line.

Comment: Sorry, the whole issue with the first line is that my keyboard covers half of the UITextView as soon as it opens, so the only way to visibly see what you're typing is to have the top line be fully viewable and have the current text position. It's probably just bad design and may be scrapped if I can't find a suitable solution.

Answer (score 1):

[UITextView -selectedRange] will return the insertion point as the location member
[UITextView -scrollRangeToVisible:] will scroll to the specified range

Combining the two will enable you to scroll to the current cursor line.

Based on your comment, it sounds like you most likely want to adjust the frame of the text view when the keyboard is shown.
Apple provides some nice notifications:
[UIWindow Class Reference - Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006817-CH3-SW18)
[UIWindow Class Reference - User Info keys](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006817-CH3-SW27)

Make sure to check the supported operating system version as iOS 5.0 brought some new, and better, notifications and user info dictionaries